# Unable to pass proper credentials to server through corporate proxy in python, but able to do it in R

Tags: python, r, authentication, ntlm

I am trying to convert an R program into Python. The R program uses the following code to pass a request to the server:

```
auth <- function() {
    httr::authenticate(Sys.getenv("proxy_usr"), 
                   Sys.getenv("proxy_auth"), type = "ntlm")
}

raw_data <- httr::POST(url_base, body = url_options, auth()) %>% 
    httr::content("text")
```

This works exactly as expected. Here's what I have  with Python:

```
import os
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth 
user = os.environ.get('proxy_usr', "")
auth_pass = os.environ.get('proxy_auth', "")
response = requests.post(url_base, data = url_options, auth = 
    HttpNtlmAuth(user, auth_pass))
return (response.text)
```

This gives me an html file back that says "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." I have tried a bunch of variations of this to no avail. What could the reason behind this be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTTPProxyAuth

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

response = requests.post(url_base, data = url_options, auth = HTTPProxyAuth("username", "password"))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. Unfortunately it didn't work. I am getting the same error as before